# Replace combination switch, make switched outlet permanently on

Tags: gfci

The old GFCI combination switch in the kitchen was used to turn the insinkerator on/off.
We prefer a pressure switch, which we know how to install.
The old combination switch is supposed to be replaced with a regular GFCI outlet. I have installed the outlet, and one red wire is left over (presumably the hot wire that was going downstream to the outlet for the insinkerator). See photo attached (the red wire is secured with a wire nut).

Question: Where should this red wire go in order to make the insinkerator outlet permanently on?

Image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gsafaug4k9sgyy4/E1BC6D0E-F966-416A-AF15-3A1F01CB4ADE.jpeg?dl=0

Comment: There's an image upload button on the editor toolbar so that your readers don't have to follow a link to understand your question. Hit the [edit] link ...

Comment: Was the garbage disposal outlet GFCI protected?